# Show that every matrix of order >1 is the sum of two singular matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that every matrix of order >1 is the sum of two singular matrices.

Let
\begin{align*}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and assume that A is of order $>1$.

I think that singular matrices $B,C$ in this problem

\begin{align*}
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n} 
\end{bmatrix},
\: \: \:
C=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then, it satisfies $B+C=A$ and $B,C$ are singular matrices.

However, I don't know why A's order $>1$..

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: A "matrix" of order $1$ is just a real number and the only singular "matrix" with order $1$ is $0$, but $0+0\ne 1$ , so $1$ (for example) does not have the desired representation.

Comment: You got the idea, but your answer is slightly incorrect: $a_{2,2}$ appears in both $B$ and $C$.

Comment: For order greater than $1$, it is enough to replace one row or column by zeros and to subtract this matrix from the given matrix.

Comment: Thank you!! I modify my answer. And, my curiosity about problem's condition is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct.

Note that for order 1 $$det(a)=0 \iff a=0$$

Thus I can only write $0$ as sum of two singular matrices $0+0=0$.